# Refresh constantly updating dict in another script

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have 2 simple python scripts running.

a.py is constantly updating a dict with information from a serial input, I would like to use the information in the a.dict in b.py but it doesn't show me the updated values.

I have tried reload(a) but that doesn't appear work.

How do I get the *live* (changing) a.dict values to be seen in b.py?

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: It's not clear how exactly you are trying to do what you describe, but generally, two scripts are two separate programs and changing a value in one of them won't have any effects in the other one.

Comment: Does running `a` actually change the file `a.py`? `b` will `import a` *from the file*, so if the file doesn't change neither will the values.

Comment: can't you just import a.py

Comment: There are too many options e.g., `import a; d = {}; while True: a.update_dict(d); print "got new dict", d` Or you could use `threading`, `multiprocessing` to move `a.update_dict()` into a different thread, process. If they are independent processes then you could apply [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

Answer (score 0):

**Using multiprocessing**

I suggest having a look at [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) and [managers](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#namespace-objects) in particular.

**Persistent Module Hack**

Here is something I wrote: [runningConfiguration.py](https://gist.github.com/niccokunzmann/5262590)

When you import this module and access attributes they are stored in a file next to the module.

Like:

```
import runningConfiguration
runningConfiguration.a = 5 # seen by all runningConfiguration modules in the same folder
```

If you change objects inside then you need to load and save

```
import runningConfiguration
runningConfiguration.d = {}
runningConfiguration.d[3] = 'a'
runningConfiguration.save()
```